# astropy sidereal time correction for AltAz

Tags: coordinates, physics, astropy, astronomy

Let's say I am watching a star, with celestial coordinates radec_coord1. Using the location of observation, time of observation and astropy package I can convert those radec coords to altaz frame. That star now has altaz_coord1 coordinates.
After an hour of time, the same star(radec_coord1 is the same) now has a new alt az coordinates, altaz_coord2, due to the rotation of the earth.
How can I transform from the altaz_coord2 to altaz_coord1? Meaning, how can I "revert" rotation of the Earth? If I do "reverting" correctly, altaz_coord2 should be pretty close(if not the same) to the altaz_coord1?
This below is my minimum reproducible example. I am using sidereal time and hour angle to correct for time difference. Is this wrong, I am not getting the results I was expecting.

> 

```
from astropy.time import Time
from astropy.coordinates import AltAz, SkyCoord, EarthLocation, get_sun, get_moon
import astropy.units as u
import numpy as np

# Define the observer's location 
observer_location = EarthLocation(lat=28*u.deg, lon=342*u.deg, height=2000*u.m)

# Define the time of the two observations
time1 = Time('2023-01-01T00:00:00')
time2 = Time('2023-01-01T01:00:00')

# Calculate Local Sidereal Time (LST) for each observation
lst1 = time1.sidereal_time('mean', observer_location)
lst2 = time2.sidereal_time('mean', observer_location)

# Define the celestial coordinates for the first observation
ra1 = 30*u.deg
dec1 = 45*u.deg

# Convert celestial coordinates to AltAz for the first observation
radec_coord1 = SkyCoord(ra1, dec1, frame='icrs', unit="deg")
altaz_coord1 = radec_coord1.transform_to(AltAz(obstime=time1, location=observer_location))

# Calculate Hour Angle for the first observation
ha1 = (lst1 - ra1).wrap_at(180*u.deg)

# Define the celestial coordinates for the second observation (replace with your actual data)
ra2 = 30*u.deg
dec2 = 45*u.deg

# Convert celestial coordinates to AltAz for the second observation
altaz_coord2 = radec_coord1.transform_to(AltAz(obstime=time2, location=observer_location))

# Calculate Hour Angle for the second observation
ha2 = (lst2 - ra2).wrap_at(180*u.deg)

# Calculate the time difference in hours
time_difference = (time2 - time1).to(u.hour).value

# Correct HA2 for the time difference
ha2_corrected = ha2 - (time_difference * 15*u.deg)

# Convert corrected HA2 and Dec2 back to AltAz
altaz_coord2_corrected = AltAz(alt=altaz_coord2.alt, az=ha2_corrected + radec_coord1.ra, obstime=time2, location=observer_location)

print("AltAz for the first observation:", altaz_coord1)
print("AltAz for the second observation (uncorrected):", altaz_coord2)
print("AltAz for the second observation (corrected):", altaz_coord2_corrected)
```

And these are the results I am getting:

```
AltAz for the first observation: <SkyCoord (AltAz: obstime=2023-01-01T00:00:00.000, location=(5361567.60088746, -1742078.91621255, 2977444.22045669) m, pressure=0.0 hPa, temperature=0.0 deg_C, relative_humidity=0.0, obswl=1.0 micron): (az, alt) in deg
    (307.16540267, 45.72305497)>
AltAz for the second observation (uncorrected): <SkyCoord (AltAz: obstime=2023-01-01T01:00:00.000, location=(5361567.60088746, -1742078.91621255, 2977444.22045669) m, pressure=0.0 hPa, temperature=0.0 deg_C, relative_humidity=0.0, obswl=1.0 micron): (az, alt) in deg
    (307.37739908, 35.12517022)>
AltAz for the second observation (corrected): <AltAz Coordinate (obstime=2023-01-01T01:00:00.000, location=(5361567.60088746, -1742078.91621255, 2977444.22045669) m, pressure=0.0 hPa, temperature=0.0 deg_C, relative_humidity=0.0, obswl=1.0 micron): (az, alt) in deg
    (82.43231165, 35.12517022)>
```